# Laravel 4 - Check if a database value is true

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

Im running Laravel 4 for my app ... Im a newbie.

I have created a small little application using the standard built in authentication and everything is working fine.

I have the User.php model and the routes file taking care of all my requests.

What i want to do, is add administrators, i have added a field in my users table which is named 'is_admin' .. its an integer of 1 or 0.

What i want to be able to do is something like the following

```
if is_admin() {
    // Do stuff here if im an admin
}
```

Can anyone help me out with how i can achieve that .. All i have at the moment is a database column.

Cheers,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually you may check if the user is an admin ot not using this:

```
if(Auth::user()->is_admin) {
    //...
}
```

Because `Auth::user()` returns the currently logged in user and `is_admin` field is available in the `users` table so if a user is logged in then you may simply check by checking the `Auth::user()->is_admin` property of the logged in user model. If a user is admin then the value is `1` and this will be true and for `0` result will be false in the `if` condition.

If you want to add a method in the user model then you may try this way:

```
public function isAdmin()
{
    return $this->is_admin;
}
```

So you may check like:

```
$user = User::find(1);
if($user->isAdmin()) {
    //...
}
```

Comment: Ohhhhhhh That first method is awesome ... I totally forgot about that!!! ... Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

```
$val = (bool)DB::table(DB::raw('DUAL'))->whereExists(function($query) use ($userId)) {
    $query->from = 'users';
    $query->where('id', $userId)->where('is_admin', 1)->select(DB::raw(1));
})->first([DB::raw(1)]);
```

This will run a `SELECT 1 FROM DUAL WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHERE id = X and is_admin = 1` query which will return a boolean if the row exists or not.

`DUAL` is a dummy table in MySQL and used so we don't have to go trough a table. `DB::raw(1)` is used as we don't need to fetch column data for this, we just want true/false.

If you're already logged and you're using Laravels `Auth` you can just do as @WereWolf mentioned.